# Autofac 2.4.5.724 API change for ReflectionExtensions IsClosingTypeOf

Tags: autofac

Does IsClosingTypeOf still exist?
What is the equivalent method in TypeExtensions?

I guess I'll have to bite the bullet and install hg and download the code. I've been trying to avoid doing this for sometime now... I'm just very busy right now with deadlines ;)

**Update** This is the code from branch 2.3

```
public static bool IsClosingTypeOf(this Type type, Type openGenericType)
{
    Enforce.ArgumentNotNull(type, "type");
    Enforce.ArgumentNotNull(openGenericType, "openGenericType");
    return type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == openGenericType;
}
```

It's not the same as `IsClosedTypeOf` I tried substituting the IsClosedTypeOf for IsClosingTypeOf but with no luck, my tests broke.

Comment: Can you please provide examples of the parameters you're using? Thanks!

Comment: Also, please indicate the specific version of Autofac you're using - we fixed some bugs in this function a version or two ago.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `IsClosedTypeOf` in type `Autofac.TypeExtensions`? It's defined in [trunk](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/src/Source/Autofac/TypeExtensions.cs) as

```
    /// <summary>Determines whether the candidate type supports any base or 
    /// interface that closes the provided generic type.</summary>
    /// <param name="this"></param>
    /// <param name="openGeneric"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool IsClosedTypeOf(this Type @this, Type openGeneric)
    {
        if (@this == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("this");
        if (openGeneric == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("openGeneric");

        if (!(openGeneric.IsGenericTypeDefinition || openGeneric.ContainsGenericParameters))
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(TypeExtensionsResources.NotOpenGenericType, openGeneric.FullName));

        return @this.GetTypesThatClose(openGeneric).Any();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Jim, I tried that but my tests failed. Looks like there were some changes from 2.3 to 2.4